# Divide screen into 1 top row and 2 columns. The two columns should be 100% height of browser

Tags: html, css

Here is a fiddle link to my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YZrae/2/

notice how there is an extra scroll bar appearing on the left side.. I need to remove this extra scroll bar but cannot figure out what I am doing wrong...

I need the left and right columns to keep their scroll bars but remove the rest that are appearing.

here is the code I used in the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div class="top_wrap"></div>
<div class="content_wrap">
  <div class="col_right_wrap"></div>
  <div class="col_left_wrap"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
.top_wrap{
background-color:red;
height:50px;
}
.content_wrap{
background-color:blue;
height:100%;
position:relative;
}
.col_right_wrap{
float:right;
height:100%;
background-color:green;
width:50%;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.col_left_wrap{
float:left;
width:49%;
height:100%;
background-color:yellow;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
div.clear { clear: both; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; font-size:0pt; margin-top: -1px; }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with a bit of jQuery, this one does it.

**Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZrae/10/).**

The code jQuery code resizes .content-wrap to be (window height - .top_wrap height). Here is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
functionHeight = function () {
    var varBrowserHeight = $(window).height();
    var varTopWrapHeight = $(".top_wrap").height();

    $(".content_wrap").css('height', (varBrowserHeight - varTopWrapHeight));
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    functionHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function (event) {
    functionHeight();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect - I am fine with the jQuery.  The other answers are good as well but this allows me the have a top banner with a fixed height regardless if the browser window height changes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because height of the columns is 100% and on top of it you are adding a row of 50px so it leads to scroll. You can try removing that extra scroll by giving height:5% to the top row and 95% to the two columns below. Or else overflow-y:hidden; but that would hide overflowing content in-case if you are planning to insert.